# Expected space consumption of skip lists

Tags: data-structures, space-complexity, skip-lists

What is the **expected** space used by the skip list after inserting n elements?

I expect that in the worst case the space consumption may grow indeﬁnitely.

Wikipedia says “Space O(n)”.

How can this be proven one way or another?

Comment: The wikipedia page says that on average each element will be in `log 1/(1-p)` of the linked lists, so `n * log 1/(1-p)` is probably a good estimate.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: The OP asks about *worst case*.

Comment: The question is, what the expected space is. note the worst case.

Comment: @user1374864: Assume the space consumption is `f(n)`. then the "expected space of worst case" is `E = f(n)*1 = f(n)`, since the "expected space of worst case" is `E(space|worst case) = 0*#space_not_worst_case + 1*#space_worst_case = 0 + 1*f(n)` Are you interested maybe in *expected* space? or *worst case*? These are two different things.

Comment: See also [the same question on Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1713/expected-space-consumption-of-skip-lists).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this thesis](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/28/root2side.pdf), which I find more reliable then wikipedia, **wikipedia is wrong**. Probabilistic Skip List is `Theta(nlogn)` worst case space complexity.

> Despite the fact that on the average the PSL performs reasonably well,
>   in the worst case its Theta(n lg n) space and Theta(n) time complexity are
>   unacceptably high

The worst case is not infinite because you can limit yourself to `f(n)` number of lists, where `f(n) = O(logn)`, and stop flipping coins when you reached this height. So, if you have `f(n)` complete rows, you get `O(nlogn)` total number of nodes, thus the space complexity in this case is `O(nlogn)`, and not `O(n)`.

---

**EDIT**:

If you are looking for *expected space* consumption, and not *worst* as initially was stated in the question then: 

Let's denote "column" as a bottom node and all the nodes "up" from it.

```
E(#nodes) = Sigma(E(#nodes_for_column_i)) (i in [1,n])
```

The above equation is true because linearity of expected value.

`E(#nodes_for_column_i) = 1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n < 2` (for each i). This is because with probability 1 it has 1 node, with p=1/2, each of these has an extra node. with p'=1/2, each of these has an extra node (total p*p'=1/4) ,.... Thus we can derive:

```
E(#nodes) = n*E(#nodes_for_each_column) = n*(1+1/2+...+1/n) < 2n = O(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's we have deterministic skiplist with N nodes. In addition to data values, list contains:

N pointers at level 1, N/2 pointers at level 2, N/4 pointers at level 3 and so on...

N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8 +..N/2^k 
is sum of geometric progression, and its limit is 2N, so maximum memory consumption is  N*SizeOf(Data) + 2*N*SizeOf(Pointer) = O(N).

I did not take into account interlevel links, but their count is about of pointer count.

Comment: The OP is asking about worst case of probabalistic skip list.

Comment: OK, my method is suitable for "balanced" skip list only.

Answer (score 0):

## Expected Space Complexity

A Skip List has `logn` layers. Each element in a Skip List appears in one or more layers. To measure the expected space complexity of a Skip List, we can evaluate the expected number of layers that an arbitrary element x appears in.

We know that x has a 100% chance of appearing only in the bottom layer, a 50% chance of appearing in both the bottom and 2nd bottom layers, a 25% chance of appearing in the bottom 3 layers, a 12.5% chance of appearing in the bottom 4 layers, and so on.

Mathematically, we can represent the expected number of layers that x appears in as follows...

`Sum(i / 2^(i-1)) from i=1 to logn`

... where `i` is the number of layers that x might appear in.

Intuitively, we can see that the above summation converges to a constant because the denominator grows at a much faster rate than the numerator. You can verify this by plugging the equation in to Wolfram Alpha (the summation converges to 4 for very large values of n). This implies that...

`[Sum(i / 2^(i-1)) from i=1 to logn] = O(1)`

So, we have demonstrated that storing an arbitrary element inside of an arbitrary Skip List requires constant space on average. To get the space complexity for storing `n` elements in a Skip List, we simply multiply by `n`.

`n*O(1) = O(n)`

Thus, Skip Lists have linear expected space complexity.

---

## Worst-Case Space Complexity

This is actually much easier. We know that there are `logn` layers, and `n` elements. In the worst case, every element is in every layer. Hence, `O(nlogn)`.